# height 100%, padding-bottom not working

Tags: css

I have the following - 
 a div with width: 100%, height: 100%,
 an svg inside the div, width: 100%, height: 100% (by default)

I apply padding to the div. Left, right and top padding work but bottom doesn't, any ideas?

http://codepen.io/BradLee/pen/EKerpY

```
<div>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"></svg>
</div>

div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: tomato;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
}

svg{
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply height:100%; and width:100%; in svg:

```
svg {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Why people down vote this answer? i didn't see any reason to downvote this answer.

Comment: Applying height and width 100% solved the issue, not sure why someone downvoted that

Answer (score 0):

Add "overflow-y: scroll; " to your div css, svg height is more than your viewport height so you need to scroll to view bottom area.